# Do all the Pieces of Eden do the same thing?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

In 16's files in Assassin's Creed 2 it identifies 4 different types of Pieces of Eden

- Apple - More commonly seen though the series
- Shroud - Shroud of Turin
- Staff - Seen in Assassin's Creed 2 and is apparently the Papal Staff
- Sword - The sword which Jeanne d'Arc used

also in Assassin's Creed 1, in the computer in the conference room it suggests that the Holy Grail is real and is a Piece of Eden.

16's files suggest that the Staff has the same ability to manipulate people as what the Apple has as apparently when the Czar lost the staff the people revolted against him, in the conference room computer it suggests that any Piece of Eden connected to the Jesus Mythos (Shroud, Holy Grail) will have the same powers as the Apple.

Since 16's files don't actually say what the Sword does, I am wondering if all the Pieces of Eden do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this *Assassin's Creed* unofficial Wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Pieces_of_Eden#Confirmed_Pieces_of_Eden), the different *Pieces of Eden* have different effects.

> Other Pieces included the Shroud, whose properties included the ability to heal the wounds of those it touched; the Ankh, capable of resurrecting the dead; and the Sword, a Piece that would pass through the hands of many great rulers through the centuries, including King Arthur and Attila the Hun.
>
> [...]
>
> According to emails read by Desmond Miles in 2012, at least one Piece of Eden existed that granted the ability to manipulate time. Concerns over possible paradoxes, however, led to Abstergo Industries locking it away.